# Detect touch on CAShapeLayer (line)

Tags: core-animation

Using the standard code I've seen on the internet, I can't detect a touch over a single `CAShapeLayer.

```
CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    CGPathRef path = ((CAShapeLayer *)[lettersArray objectAtIndex:1]).path;

    if(CGPathContainsPoint(path, nil, p, NO))
    {
        ((CAShapeLayer *)[lettersArray objectAtIndex:0]).position = p;
        NSLog(@"Touched");
    }
```

Do I need to have at least some area rather just a segment?

Comment: Have you looked at [this post about hit testing CGPath](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your path needs to have some area for CGPathContainsPoint to test that a point is inside it. What you probably want to do is [find the distance from the point to the line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) and test that that’s within a certain threshold.

Note that the formulas in that article give you the distance to the *line* rather than the *segment*; if the closest point on the line is beyond the boundaries of the segment, you need to calculate the distance from your point to the segment’s endpoint as well.

Comment: So analytical geometry? I'll try it. To get the parameters of the line, I need to calculate them myself? i.e. I take `CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];` and check its distance to the line that of which I have its equation?

Comment: Exactly. I’d recommend taking the vector route over the Cartesian-coordinate one—it’s easier to work out the endpoint thing in that form.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy try this code it work for me

```
CGPathRef originalPath = shapeView.path;  //The single-line path

//Use the values you use to draw the path onscreen,
//or use a width representing how far the user can touch
//for it to be recognized by the path.
//For example, for an error tolerance of 4px, use a width of 8px.
CGPathRef strokedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(originalPath, NULL, path.lineWidth, path.lineCapStyle, path.lineJoinStyle, path.miterLimit);
BOOL pathContainsPoint = CGPathContainsPoint(strokedPath, NULL, touchLocation, NO);

NSLog(pathContainsPoint ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    for (id sublayer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
        BOOL touchInLayer = NO;
        if ([sublayer isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
            CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = sublayer;
            if (CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, 0, touchLocation, YES)) {
                // This touch is in this shape layer
                touchInLayer = YES;
            }
        } else {
            CALayer *layer = sublayer;
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(layer.frame, touchLocation)) {
                // Touch is in this rectangular layer
                touchInLayer = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}